# is using window.onload to execute an anonymous function the same base principle as the module pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, dom, window

when using the module pattern in js i've notice that the main benefits are private members and not cluttering the global namespace, but what i wanted to know is, is this:

```
(function(){
   //some code...
})();
```

the same as this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    //some code...
}
```

they both provide private members and both don't clutter the global namespace. the only difference i can see is that if both are manipulating DOM elements the second one can be called anywhere within the document (because of document.onload) while the first has to be called ether at the bottom of the body node or right after the close of the body node.

are there any other differences between the two that i may be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major difference is that the latter will overwrite any existing `window.onload` that may have been set earlier on the page — and will, in turn, be overwritten by any later ones. (This can be addressed by using [`window.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) instead.)

Comment: wow i don't know why i didn't see that, so the module pattern is one level above an anonymous window.onload execution meaning you can have more than 1?

Comment: Well, you're not using the term "module pattern" correctly. But yes, `(function(){ ... })();` runs the function immediately -- aside from scoping issues, it's just like plopping `...` directly into your script -- so you can use that syntax arbitrarily many times on a page, just like you can use the `alert('...')` syntax or the `var ... = ...` syntax many times on a page.

Comment: "Well, you're not using the term "module pattern"correctly" is there a lot more to the basis of this pattern?

Comment: @codewombat: Yes; see http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth. The immediately-executed function expressions are the underpinning of the module pattern, but there's a lot more to it than that. Actually, I don't know if I would consider immediately-executed function expressions to even be *part* of the module pattern, so much as a *prerequisite* for it, but I suppose that's a matter of definitions. Others might disagree.